# Adding a overlaying shadow on an image

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a shadow over the bottom part of an image like in the example I have provided. I was thinking about just overlaying a linear gradient and changing the opacity maybe, I am not even sure how accurately this would portray it but I am assuming there is a better way.

To be clear, I do NOT want to create a shadow on the outside of the image, I want it to overlay the image.

[image]

Thank you guys for any insight at all!

Comment: You’re fine, that’s definitely a linear gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear Gradient to achieve using expo linear gradient

```
<View style={{borderBottomLeftRadius: 30, borderBottomRightRadius: 30, overflow: 'hidden', top: 125}}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['transparent', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)', ]}
        style={{width: 300, height: 100,}}>
      </LinearGradient>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good library here to use, the usage in their example provided exactly what I am looking for with easy to use props.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inset-shadow

Comment: IMO, adding another dependency for something that can be done relatively easily with an absolutely-positioned gradient seems redundant. But do you :)

Comment: I was thinking about that as well, It also provides less room to work with using the library. A linear gradient will give me the best result. This is definitely a quick fix though I will edit it and add code for a linear gradient once I complete it tomorrow!

Answer (score -2):

[image: Shadow example]

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Image, } from "react-native";

const ShadowExample = (props) => {
  const imageURL = "https://designpress-10674.kxcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/funny-horse-pictures/happy-to-see-you.jpg"
  const localStyles = {
    withShadowStyle: {
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "center",
      backgroundColor: "white",
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
      },
      shadowOpacity: 0.50,
      shadowRadius: 4,

      elevation: 3,      
    },     
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <View style={{ ...localStyles.withShadowStyle, padding: 10, }}>
        <Image source={{ uri: imageURL, }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200, }} />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}
```

#### P.S. Check out the React Native shadow generator:

> https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/

Comment: This doesnt answer what I am looking for, this gives a shadow on the outside of the image. I want the shadow overlaying the image

Comment: @JustinPriede - well, I'm not gonna try again... Anyway, try updating your question with more examples of the desired effect. Another user may have an answer.